# Cannot use latexmk on MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, latexmk, perl

I'd like to use latexmk in order to compile my LaTeX documents and have Strawberry Perl v5.24.0 installed on my PC.
Whenever I type in

```
latexmk myFile.tex
```

at the command prompt I'm getting the following error:

```
latexmk: The script could not be found.
latexmk: Data: scriptEngine="perl", name="latexmk", path="scripts/latexmk/perl/latexmk.pl"
```

but the latexkmk.pl perl script is actually located in

```
scripts/latexmk
```

and there is no perl subfolder in the path.
I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 portable on Windows 10 64 bit.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: latexmf.pl was previously in latexmk/perl, but moved with the last update. Your script.ini seems not have been adapted. Did you check for updates?

Comment: I've just updated my MiKTeX distribution and now `latekmk` works like a charm! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an update (see comments).